# Why does Sidekiq not close old connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sidekiq, celluloid

My Rails 4.1 application uses Sidekiq to run measurements in Celluloid actors. It continously runs out of database connections. It appears that Sidekiq opens 2 connections per job, and old connections  never get closed properly.

### What the system does

- Every 15 minutes, I start a `MeasurementWorker`. By calling `MeasurementWorker.perform_async(measurement.id)`. It does this:

```rb
    class MeasurementWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker
      sidekiq_options retry: false, backtrace: true

      def perform(measurement_id, force = false)
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
            Measurement.find(measurement_id).run
        end
      end
    end
```

- Inside this measurement, when I call `.run`, it does this:

```rb
    # various checks if measurement can be run at all, using AR
    # ...
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      # (I used to have a Timeout.timeout here, but removed it for the
      # sake of simplification)
        @connection = MeasurementConnection.new do |event_info|
          event = Event.new
          event.assign_attributes(event_info)
          event.save
        end
        while @connection.measuring?; end
      end # with_connection
    rescue Exception => e
      # an exception happened, e.g. something during the measurement itself
      # log error (left out here for brevity)
    else
      # all went fine, 
      # save this measurement via AR
    ensure
      # Close and terminate the actor to free up the websocket,
      # if it is still actively measuring something.
      if @connection
        if @connection.alive? and @connection.measuring?
          @connection.close
        end
        while @connection.alive?
          @connection.terminate
          sleep(0.01)
        end
      end
    end
```

- The `MeasurementConnection` is a simple Celluloid actor. There is no AR-related code inside this actor.

### Configuration

- Unicorn: concurrency set to 3
- Sidekiq 3.3.0: concurrency set to 50, and in the initializer:

```rb
    Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
      if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
        config['pool']              = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2
        config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 5
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
      end
    end
```

- `database.yml`: pool set to 60, reaping frequency 5
- PostgreSQL 9.3: maximum connections are 2000, no other modifications

### The problem: too many connections open

When I check `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`, I see that there are some old connections open with no Sidekiq workers busy, and some new where they are:

```
16661 measurement 6354  16384 measurement unicorn worker[0] -c /home/web...E production -D -l0.0.0.0:8080 127.0.0.1   50775 2015-02-20 12:52:48.572551+01   2015-02-20 13:05:05.773178+01 2015-02-20 13:05:05.773565+01 f idle  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "measurements"
16661 measurement 6406  16384 measurement unicorn worker[2] -c /home/web...E production -D -l0.0.0.0:8080 127.0.0.1   50776 2015-02-20 12:53:59.636414+01   2015-02-20 13:04:53.930305+01 2015-02-20 13:04:53.931+01  f idle  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "measurements"
16661 measurement 6687  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50801 2015-02-20 13:00:05.14621+01    2015-02-20 13:04:49.558589+01 2015-02-20 13:04:49.558835+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7042  16384 measurement unicorn worker[1] -c /home/web...E production -D -l0.0.0.0:8080 127.0.0.1   50997 2015-02-20 13:00:34.874675+01   2015-02-20 13:00:35.376593+01 2015-02-20 13:00:35.376979+01 f idle  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "measurements"
16661 measurement 6668  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50781 2015-02-20 13:00:04.883553+01   2015-02-20 13:04:19.108365+01 2015-02-20 13:04:19.108567+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6669  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50782 2015-02-20 13:00:04.908349+01   2015-02-20 13:03:57.683036+01 2015-02-20 13:03:57.683236+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6672  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50786 2015-02-20 13:00:04.962251+01   2015-02-20 13:04:32.395137+01 2015-02-20 13:04:32.395344+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6674  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50788 2015-02-20 13:00:04.98456+01    2015-02-20 13:04:32.396335+01 2015-02-20 13:04:32.39652+01  f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6676  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50790 2015-02-20 13:00:05.006847+01   2015-02-20 13:04:19.059628+01 2015-02-20 13:04:19.059831+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6678  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50792 2015-02-20 13:00:05.029448+01   2015-02-20 13:04:23.730293+01 2015-02-20 13:04:23.730523+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6680  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50794 2015-02-20 13:00:05.051932+01   2015-02-20 13:04:49.557435+01 2015-02-20 13:04:49.557633+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6684  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50798 2015-02-20 13:00:05.124225+01   2015-02-20 13:03:51.693799+01 2015-02-20 13:03:51.694034+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6690  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50804 2015-02-20 13:00:05.168099+01   2015-02-20 13:04:54.849239+01 2015-02-20 13:04:54.849459+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6693  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50807 2015-02-20 13:00:05.189661+01   2015-02-20 13:04:18.688459+01 2015-02-20 13:04:18.688732+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6696  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50810 2015-02-20 13:00:05.210659+01   2015-02-20 13:03:57.68424+01  2015-02-20 13:03:57.684483+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6699  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50813 2015-02-20 13:00:05.231641+01   2015-02-20 13:04:04.962397+01 2015-02-20 13:04:04.96258+01  f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6701  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50815 2015-02-20 13:00:05.252357+01   2015-02-20 13:04:41.685372+01 2015-02-20 13:04:41.685594+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 6706  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [0 of 50 busy]  127.0.0.1   50820 2015-02-20 13:00:05.273301+01   2015-02-20 13:04:23.733488+01 2015-02-20 13:04:23.733681+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7003  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50967 2015-02-20 13:00:09.004487+01   2015-02-20 13:02:02.036429+01 2015-02-20 13:02:02.036696+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7005  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50969 2015-02-20 13:00:11.118961+01   2015-02-20 13:02:48.341078+01 2015-02-20 13:02:48.341294+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7006  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50970 2015-02-20 13:00:12.245408+01   2015-02-20 13:03:04.300372+01 2015-02-20 13:03:04.300575+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7007  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50971 2015-02-20 13:00:12.648636+01   2015-02-20 13:03:01.855616+01 2015-02-20 13:03:01.85588+01  f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7008  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50972 2015-02-20 13:00:12.956139+01   2015-02-20 13:03:13.840023+01 2015-02-20 13:03:13.840466+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7009  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50973 2015-02-20 13:00:13.02424+01    2015-02-20 13:02:50.115996+01 2015-02-20 13:02:50.116259+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7010  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50974 2015-02-20 13:00:13.0909+01   2015-02-20 13:03:09.968+01  2015-02-20 13:03:09.968284+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7014  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50976 2015-02-20 13:00:14.929822+01   2015-02-20 13:03:20.183195+01 2015-02-20 13:03:20.183467+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7020  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50980 2015-02-20 13:00:22.498892+01   2015-02-20 13:03:29.887257+01 2015-02-20 13:03:29.887599+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7021  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50981 2015-02-20 13:00:22.898087+01   2015-02-20 13:03:39.689939+01 2015-02-20 13:03:39.69798+01  f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7022  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50982 2015-02-20 13:00:23.215846+01   2015-02-20 13:03:03.918339+01 2015-02-20 13:03:03.918613+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7023  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50983 2015-02-20 13:00:23.930861+01   2015-02-20 13:03:51.504525+01 2015-02-20 13:03:51.512786+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7025  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50985 2015-02-20 13:00:24.409999+01   2015-02-20 13:03:16.000375+01 2015-02-20 13:03:16.006178+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7027  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50986 2015-02-20 13:00:25.786321+01   2015-02-20 13:03:22.631091+01 2015-02-20 13:03:22.631353+01 f idle  COMMIT
16661 measurement 7045  16384 measurement sidekiq 3.3.0 measurement [15 of 50 busy] 127.0.0.1   50998 2015-02-20 13:00:48.004036+01   2015-02-20 13:03:39.717124+01 2015-02-20 13:03:39.722956+01 f idle  COMMIT
```

In total, there are 34 connections, but I only ran 15 measurements.

In `sidekiq.log`, they all show as *done*:

```
2015-02-20T12:00:04.879Z 6235 TID-osgop8md0 MeasurementWorker JID-1cdcd44bf41fefe9ddca21ac INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.907Z 6235 TID-osgoox8hg MeasurementWorker JID-79f4d1ff6692248682ba93dd INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.939Z 6235 TID-osgoos38k MeasurementWorker JID-09f95fbccd2438d17916d425 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.940Z 6235 TID-osgoorlmo MeasurementWorker JID-be1a57871f26146e9884107e INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.959Z 6235 TID-osgoow16k MeasurementWorker JID-e296efec897c23629b96e99f INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.968Z 6235 TID-osgoouytg MeasurementWorker JID-c6a57700872b7fe427e33664 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.984Z 6235 TID-osgooz63k MeasurementWorker JID-f7448eaffe109882130497ca INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:04.998Z 6235 TID-osgoozvzs MeasurementWorker JID-c55c04f3424268fba50ec048 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.014Z 6235 TID-osgooyr6c MeasurementWorker JID-01bd303e953fd2998fe3f8d1 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.030Z 6235 TID-osgon0ums MeasurementWorker JID-6949c5c81b4c254046f0c585 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.042Z 6235 TID-osgomw0g8 MeasurementWorker JID-cc03b717f81dd6fb0f58a946 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.111Z 6235 TID-osgomlno8 MeasurementWorker JID-10eebcd76113f3565d8265ca INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.113Z 6235 TID-osgomjzzw MeasurementWorker JID-b0536d9a029faed0ba8eb5d3 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.114Z 6235 TID-osgomhyms MeasurementWorker JID-1f6624314afd8e0ae611599f INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:00:05.115Z 6235 TID-osgolgzoc MeasurementWorker JID-24e87960d7e7fbd871037dd3 INFO: start
2015-02-20T12:02:02.333Z 6235 TID-osgomw0g8 MeasurementWorker JID-cc03b717f81dd6fb0f58a946 INFO: done: 117.291 sec
2015-02-20T12:02:48.983Z 6235 TID-osgoox8hg MeasurementWorker JID-79f4d1ff6692248682ba93dd INFO: done: 164.077 sec
2015-02-20T12:02:50.688Z 6235 TID-osgomlno8 MeasurementWorker JID-10eebcd76113f3565d8265ca INFO: done: 165.577 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:02.429Z 6235 TID-osgolgzoc MeasurementWorker JID-24e87960d7e7fbd871037dd3 INFO: done: 177.314 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:04.581Z 6235 TID-osgoorlmo MeasurementWorker JID-be1a57871f26146e9884107e INFO: done: 179.641 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:09.453Z 6235 TID-osgop8md0 MeasurementWorker JID-1cdcd44bf41fefe9ddca21ac INFO: done: 184.573 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:10.362Z 6235 TID-osgoouytg MeasurementWorker JID-c6a57700872b7fe427e33664 INFO: done: 185.394 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:14.232Z 6235 TID-osgomjzzw MeasurementWorker JID-b0536d9a029faed0ba8eb5d3 INFO: done: 189.118 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:16.347Z 6235 TID-osgoos38k MeasurementWorker JID-09f95fbccd2438d17916d425 INFO: done: 191.408 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:20.398Z 6235 TID-osgoow16k MeasurementWorker JID-e296efec897c23629b96e99f INFO: done: 195.439 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:22.947Z 6235 TID-osgomhyms MeasurementWorker JID-1f6624314afd8e0ae611599f INFO: done: 197.833 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:30.212Z 6235 TID-osgooz63k MeasurementWorker JID-f7448eaffe109882130497ca INFO: done: 205.228 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:39.931Z 6235 TID-osgooyr6c MeasurementWorker JID-01bd303e953fd2998fe3f8d1 INFO: done: 214.918 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:39.936Z 6235 TID-osgon0ums MeasurementWorker JID-6949c5c81b4c254046f0c585 INFO: done: 214.906 sec
2015-02-20T12:03:51.694Z 6235 TID-osgoozvzs MeasurementWorker JID-c55c04f3424268fba50ec048 INFO: done: 226.696 sec
```

So, for every measurement, Sidekiq seems to open 2 connections, but it never closes them. What should I do?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['production']['pool'] = 25`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? I've set the pool to much higher values already, and it just means that it takes longer for it to fill up.

Comment: Same Issue on 
Rails 4.1
Sidekiq 3.3.0
100 Postgres Connections in db.yml
When we have a huge queue it is not closing the connections

Comment: @user2699706 Good to know I'm not the only one. I'm going to make a Sidekiq bug report maybe.. or bounty this question in a few days.

Comment: Does MeasurementConnection access active record? Does it checkin/out its connection like the worker you showed?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Yes, it loads and creates various ActiveRecord objects. I don't do any expliciit connection checkin/checkout — would I need to do that explicitly again?

Comment: yes - new actor will in general run on a different thread if my memory of celluloid is correct

Comment: @FrederickCheung I see, thanks, so… assuming `MeasurementConnection` is a Celluloid Actor, what code would I need to put where?

Comment: just chiming in here, we are experiencing the same behaviour as well, and not using Celluloid for our actors.

Comment: 8 years later: was this solved? Did the solution of @kurenn work for you?

Comment: @jgomo3 I've moved on from this code base but we ended up using pgbouncer (https://www.pgbouncer.org/) to work around the issue. Now I'm using recent Sidekiq in another project and we're not facing any issues.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that your celluloid actor is leaking connections: when you do something requiring an active record connection in a new thread (or even finer apparently) AR automatically checks out a connection but won't check it back in automatically.

If you bracket your database accessing code with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  # do stuff
end
```

that should clear up any connections created within (as you do in your sidekiq worker).

Alternatively you could try explicitly checking out a connection

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout
```

and then checking it back in in your finalizer

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin @connection
```

If your actor is very long lived you might end up hogging the connection longer than you need it though (the flipside is that it will be inefficient to be checking a connection in and out in a tight loop)

Comment: No dice. In the Actor's initializer, I used the `checkout` method, and in its finalizer, I put the `checkin` line. I also removed all AR-related code from my Actor. Still it keeps old connections open, two for every measurement. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Remove `Timeout.timeout`, don't ever use that API.  Use `with_connection`.  Timeout.timeout is terribly broken and spins off it's own thread internally which is why your with_connection is not working and connections are still leaking.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. But I need the thing to time out after 10 minutes or so, any alternative?

Comment: Use real timeouts, not Ruby's fake timeout, e.g. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#connection-options

Comment: Hm, maybe it wasn't so obvious from my description of the system, but it's not about a database timeout (e.g. a timeout caused by failure to connect to Postgres or MySQL). Simply put, the worker should not run for more than, say, 10 minutes. If it does, I want to know about it — that's what I did by catching a Timeout error.

Comment: There's no way to do this in a multi-threaded system that I'm aware of.

Comment: So there's no way to get `Timeout.timeout` to close its connection (and shouldn't a thread close its connections anyway when it's done?), or re-use the outer one (i.e. the one from the worker)? I could use an outside job to watch for measurement workers that take too long, but how would I make sure that aborting them also checks in their DB connections? ([This does not seem to achieve that](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-cancel-a-sidekiq-job)).

Comment: I removed the Timeout and replaced with a `with_connection` block, but it's still leaking the connection. Basically, when I run only one measurement, it opens two connections, one saying `0 of 50 busy` and another `1 of 50 busy`. When the job finishes (as indicated by the sidekiq log), both connections are kept idle in Postgres.

Answer (score 7):

I worked with sidekiq recently and did this:

```
def perform(bulk_query)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
   connection.execute(bulk_query)
  end
ensure
 # We make sure sidekiq closes the ActiveRecord connection
 ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

It is working great for me!